# About creating repositories for each model in Laravel

Tags: laravel, repository

I've just started learning about laravel repositories and a question quickly came to my mind concerning repositories and models.

Lets say I have 20 models in the `app/models` directory. Does this mean that I need to make 20 different repositories if I want to make my application more flexible when switching ORMs for example? When should I choose to create repository?

Comment: I think the book `Laravel: From Apprentice to Artisan` can likely give you a better understanding of when to use a repository.

Comment: No. Strictly speaking, you will not create `N` repository classes because you have `N` models. You will have a repository class per aggregate root object.

Comment: But as I understand, I still have to create a repository for every model that I want to use, right?

Comment: [Check this article](http://heera.it/laravel-repository-pattern#.U6KT__mSySo).

Answer (score 1):

> Does this mean that I need to make 20 different repositories if I want to make my application more flexible when switching ORMs for example?

No. It does not. You can implement a base repository with all of the basic persistence functionality, such as find, save, all, etc.

Then you can use reflection to simply wrap the calls to the underlying model object.

```
class BaseRepository
{
     private $type;
     public function constructor($type){
          $this->type = $type;
     }

     /**
      * all
      *
      * @return array all the elements from datastore
      */
     public function all()
     {
      $reflectionMethod = new \ReflectionMethod($this->type, 'all');

      return $reflectionMethod->invoke(null);
     }
}
```

Then in your controller or wherever you can initialize the repository with the specified type like so:

```
$repo = new BaseRepo('\FullyQualified\ModelNamespace\Model');
var_dump($repo->all());
```

> When should I choose to create repository?

Answering this is a little more hairy. There is a lot of debate regarding how valuable the repository model truly is when writing an application, especially when you already have substantial abstraction with the model layer from Laravel.

I would assess whether or not to use the repository pattern based on my answers to a couple of questions:

> ```
> 1. How likely is this app to be a long term project? (The longer you expect the code to be around the more benefit you will gain from using a repository)
> 2. What level of abstraction is the stakeholder willing to pay for? (Repositories add flexibility, but cost more up front in terms of cost and time.)
> ```

In general for everything but the most trivial of apps, I think that the repository pattern is worth the extra expense  up front and it is your job to help the stake holder understand that in the long term it will be substantially cheaper to maintain, test, and change.